# Richfaces 4 Ajax:queue inputTextArea not queuing

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I've been trying to put a queue onto a text area, and it is not cooperating.  I'll list the relevant section of code below.

```
<h:form>
    <a4j:queue requestDelay="1000" ignoreDupResponses="true"/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h:outputText value="Notes:"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h:inputTextarea value="#{MyActionBean.notes}">
                    <a4j:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{MyActionBean.updateNotes}"/>
                </h:inputTextarea>
```

The notes get updated as expected, but there is no delay between requests.  Is there some bug in my code, do textAreas not work for this?  Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Just for good measure, tried the following code as well, but it didn't work either.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" width="100%">
    <h:outputText value="Notes:"/>
    <h:inputTextarea value="#{MyActionBean.notes}">
        <a4j:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{MyActionBean.updateNotes}">
            <a4j:attachQueue id="notesQueue" requestDelay="1000"/>
        </a4j:ajax>
    </h:inputTextArea>
</h:panelGrid>
```

For reference, the technology versions:
JBoss AS 7, Seam 2.3.0, Richfaces 4.2.2, JSF 2.1

Answer (score 0):

For your case you need to nest `a4j:attachQueue` inside `a4j`. Try to run the code below and you'll notice that you'll get an output on the console after 15 seconds.

```
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <a4j:queue name='Y' requestDelay="3000" ignoreDupResponses="true"/>
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" width="100%">
            <h:outputText value="Notes:"/>
            <h:inputTextarea value="#{MyActionBean.notes}">
                <a4j:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{MyActionBean.updateNotes}">
                    <a4j:attachQueue requestDelay="3000"/> 
                </a4j:ajax>             
            </h:inputTextarea>
            <a4j:status>
                <f:facet name="start">
                    Please wait
                </f:facet>
            </a4j:status>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

You can use this [link if you need more information](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/A4jqueueIn4x)

**UPDATE**

I stripped down the code you sent to the bare minimum and I'm sorry to say that it is still working on my end with JBoss. Your issue could be somewhere else (e,g. your ajax might be failing for some reason since you told me "Please Wait" was not appearing).  However, I should mention that I'm not familiar with JBoss' conversation scope so I changed it to `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` (but I don't think that should matter because it was still working when it was requestscoped). I'm including all the code so you can test it yourself as a separate project. Also, since we are using a queue I changed the logging location from `updateNotes` to `setReport` so that I could be absolutely certain that the characters were actually being queued. When I typed "This is a test", the only output I saw was the entire String and not each character.

**AssessmentCheckListAction.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named; 
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped; 

@Named(value="AssessmentChecklistAction")
@SessionScoped
public class AssessmentCheckListAction implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4970638494437413924L;
    private String report;

    public AssessmentCheckListAction() {
    }

    public void updateNotes() {
        //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().log(report);
        //Logging the setter to make sure everything was queued
    }

    public String getReport() {
        return report;
    }

    public void setReport(String report) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().log(report);
        this.report = report;
        //left blank
    }
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"                    
                        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"                
                        xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
                        template="template.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:form>
                    <a4j:queue requestDelay="3000" ignoreDupResponses="true"/>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" width="100%">
                        <h:outputText value="Notes:"/>
                        <h:inputTextarea value="#{AssessmentChecklistAction.report}">
                            <a4j:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{AssessmentChecklistAction.updateNotes}">
                                <a4j:attachQueue requestDelay="3000"/> 
                            </a4j:ajax>             
                        </h:inputTextarea>
                        <a4j:status>
                            <f:facet name="start">
                                Please wait
                            </f:facet>
                        </a4j:status>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:form>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**template.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>              
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <ui:insert name="content"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried implementing this, but it is still sending each request to the server.  The differences I see between your example and my code is that mine is wrapped in a <ui:composition>, and this application is built on Seam, so it's using the Name annotation rather than ManagedBean annotation.  (Since this is supposed to be a client side behavior, I don't imagine that's the issue)

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply.  I think we're on the same page, in that by adding ajax to the form element, we're asking the client side to queue requests rather than send them immediately.  I added the <a4j:ajax event="keyup" listener=#{...}> <a4j:attacheQueue requestDelay="15000"/> </a4j:ajax>  But when I log the update notes method, it is still sending every character.  Firebug also shows a request for every character

Comment: I tried running the sample code you provided, but it resulted in the same behavior.  This action bean is using conversation scope.  The ui:composition is being included in a layout.  The basic structure (minus all the extras) <html> <h:head></h:head> <h:body> <ui:insert name="content"/> </h:body> </html>  There aren't any forms in the layout, and it's submitting the form data as expected, so no nested forms.

Comment: To answer the other thing, this project is build by doing a clean and build through maven.  It actually copies a fresh war file to the JBoss deploy directory when I build it.

Comment: I copy and pasted the code sample into the program, but the "Please Wait" never appeared.  I'm using logs instead of system.out.println for the server side, but they show updates for every character.

Comment: I'm still kind of new to asking questions on stack overflow.  What is the best way to send a copy of what I'm doing?

Comment: The link is https://www.dropbox.com/sh/owp3n6csowi7z3x/UY5b9kpSM3  It includes a simplified version of the 3 pieces in play.  Let me know if I've missed anything

Comment: It would take me more time than I have today to put together a simplified war file that shows the error.  I'll be unavailable for the next 2 weeks, so I may just need to leave it as is for now.

Comment: @drandall Understood...I'll update you anyway if there's any progress anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still unsolved.  More pressing matters have kept me from digging further into it.